# My SQL unknown column on Left Join

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm stuck on a left join and can't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting an unknown column on '_JobTable.JobTypeID' in 'on clause', but cannot work it out.

Can anyone point out what I simply am overlooking and going to hit myself in the head for later?

```
SELECT
_RefTable.RefID,
_JobTable.JobID,
_Client.ClientName,
_Type.Description,
_Job.JobDetails,
_RefTable.SiteID,
_RefTable.SiteName,
_RefTable.SiteAddressState,
_RefTable.SiteAddressSuburb

from _RefTable 

LEFT JOIN(
            SELECT
            _JobTable.JobID,
            _JobTable.JobTypeID,
            _JobTypeTable.Description
            FROM  _JobTable, _JobTypeTable WHERE _JobTable.JobTypeID = _JobTypeTable.JobTypeID
            ) as _Type on _JobTable.JobTypeID = _Type.JobTypeID

LEFT JOIN(
            SELECT
            _RefTable.RefID,
            _ClientTable.ClientName
            FROM _RefTable, _ClientTable WHERE _RefTable.ClientID = _ClientTable.ClientID
            ) as _Client on _RefTable.RefID = _Client.RefID

LEFT JOIN(
            SELECT
            _RefTable.RefID,
            _JobTable.JobID,
            _JobTable.JobDetails
            FROM  _RefTable, _JobTable  WHERE _RefTable.RefID = _JobTable.RefID 
            ) as _Job on _RefTable.RefID = _Job.RefID
```

Comment: Your join condition doesn't make sense, its the same as inside the query , you need to compare _RefTable to _Type so I'm guessing the ON condition should be something like : _Type.jobtypeID = _reftable.jobtypeID

Comment: :) I didn't read ur comments. You got it. I just deleted my ans. Go ahead posting ur ans.

Comment: There are no subqueries required here. And don't mix implicit and explicit join syntax. In fact don't use implicit (comma-) join syntax at all.

Comment: I did say I would hit myself in the head. I was over thinking it for the fields I was using and should haven't worried about the left joins. Working with Where statements and linking the type table. Thanks guys

Comment: This looks like *under* thinking